# iPad netservice with more devices

Tags: ipad, device, nsnetservice

Heey

I want to make a netservice where more ipads can connect to at the same time.

I made a one 1 iPad open a NSNetservice and open the in- and outputstream.

I started a netservice on iPad A,

When connecting with iPad B to iPad A this just works fine.
But when iPad C tries to connect the following happens:
 - Tries to resolve the NSNetService.
 - Resolves succesfull
 - Open input stream
 - Open output stream (eventCode equals NSStreamEventOpenCompleted)
 - End encountered

Because of the end encounters i cant connect, thats clear for me, but how do i make it work?

Is it possible to connect with more devices on the same netstream? Or do i have to make another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to create a new thread for each connection. At least, this worked for me when I built a message app for the iPhone. Each connection will hold the thread, and wait for a response (the thread will 'freeze').

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you be more specific?
Do i have to open more NetServices?
Thanks

Comment: I once made a chat app, and users could connect to my iPhone (server) to talk to eachother (clients)... Each client connection had his own thread...

http://www.iphoneexamples.com/

There you'll find how to ;)